# Change variable each loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi I have a very simple question. I need to fetch a new value from my state, on each loop. On the first loop I need to bind to varCase.intro1 -> Next I need to bind to varCase.intro2 and so on. I know how to change the key in the object I'm trying to create from this, but I'm not sure how to change the value dynamically.

If you have a solution where I don't need to create the constants each loop that would also be preferred (since I have a lot of keys in the full object).

Thanks.

I've tried setting it like this const intro = [varCase.intro + i] but it returns NaN (which I guess makes sense).

```
const { varCase, formCount } = this.state;

for (let i = 1; i <= formCount; i++) {
    const intro = varCase.intro[i];
}

const obj = {
    ['diff' + i]: {intro: intro}
```

Comment: Try creating an (empty) object *before* the loop, then create (assign) the properties *inside* the loop. Doing anything after the loop won't help.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify more what you want to accomplish in the end? It doesn't feel like you should use state like this.

Comment: the more I read the question, the more confused I feel.

Comment: I have a dynamic form, where the number of input fields is variable. When the user puts information into the input field, the state is updated to something like this (assuming the user made 3 input fields): 
state = { varCase: { intro1: firstvalue, intro2: secondvalue, intro3: thirdvalue }}

I need to then somehow extract that information into a different object and make an object i want to send to axios. It should look like this:
obj = { diff1: {intro: firstvalue}, diff2: {intro: secondvalue}, diff3: {intro: thirdvalue} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.` to get the value from an object when you know the key. When the key is dynamic, you can use `[]`. Example `varCase["intro"+i];`

```
const { varCase, formCount } = this.state;
let finalObj = {}

for (let i = 1; i <= formCount; i++) {
    finalObj["diff" + i] = {intro : varCase["intro"+i]}
}

console.log(finalObj);
```

In the example you gave, you are creating the `intro` variable inside the for loop. This cant be accessed outside.

Updated the answer reading your comment. You can modify the finalObj as you need

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. And it's such a clean solution as well, it's perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
var intro = {}

for (let i = 1; i <= formCount; i++) {
    if //your condition {
        intro[i] = varCase.intro[i];
    }
}
```

to call the intro you need:

```
intro['1']
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you need exactly.  If this doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Yeah, my issue is that I don't need to call varCase.intro.1 and varCase.intro.2 and so on. I need to call varCase.intro1 and varCase.intro2.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from @Bergi's comment, this will achieve what you want it to. I've made some assumptions about what your prop object looks like:

```
const { varCase, formCount } = {
    varCase: {
        intro: ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    formCount: 3
}

const intro = {}

for (let i = 0; i < formCount; i++) {
    const propName = `diff${i}`
    Object.assign(intro, { [propName]: varCase.intro[i] });
}

console.log("INTRO: ", intro); // Outputs "INTRO: " Object { diff0: 
                               // "A", diff1: "B", diff2: "C" }
```

But I'm not sure why you would want to do it this way!